# Handle touch/drag event in scrollview - android

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, ontouchlistener, android-scrollview

I am using touch listener on my views to drag them. `findViewById(R.id.myimage1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());`

Unfortunately there are lots of views therefore I have to stack them in a scrollview.

**Here is the touch listener:**

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Because of this touch listnener I am unable to scroll the listview.
When I try to scroll, the touch listener fires and view's shadow is created instead of scroll.

How can I use both events or can use **Drag n Drop** functionality in a **ScrollView**

Comment: here is an [article](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf) with code examples. Actually it concerns RecyclerView but that info is also relevant for ScrollView too.